# React - timed action does not load specific component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

What I want: when the timer hits 0 seconds, the app mounts one component and hides others.
What happens: nothing.

I'm working on React single page app. I'm having a problem with the behavior of the timer when it hits 0. I want it to hide the Questions and Timer components and show just the Results component. Right now, the logic is in timerZero, but I did try putting it in startTimer and/or clickStart, but none of those combinations worked.

I've also noticed that if you select answers after the timer hits 0, it will continue console logging "Time's up!" on every selection. Hitting submit after 0 seconds will still take you to the resultsDiv with the correct scores but does not hide the timer as instructed.

Repo: https://github.com/irene-rojas/pixar-react

App

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Timer from "./Timer";
import Questions from "./Questions/Questions.js";
import Results from "../src/Results";

class App extends Component {

state = {
    totalTrue: 0,
    totalFalse: 0,
    showTimer: true,
    showQuestions: false,
    showResults: false,
}

clickStart = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("start button clicked");
    this.setState(
        {showQuestions: true}
    )
}

// submit button
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit button clicked");
    this.setState(
        {showResults: true,
        showQuestions: false,
        showTimer: false}
        // timer still appears in resultsDiv
    )
};

timerZero = () => {
    if (this.state.timer === 0) {
    this.setState(
        {showResults: true,
        showQuestions: false,
        showTimer: false}
    )
    }
    // nothing happens >:(
};

callbackHandlerFunction = ( selectedOption ) => {
    const answerValue = selectedOption.value;
    if (answerValue === true) {
        this.setState({totalTrue: this.state.totalTrue + 1}, () => {
            console.log(`New TotalTrue: ${this.state.totalTrue}`);
        });
    };
    if (answerValue === false) {
        this.setState({totalFalse: this.state.totalFalse + 1}, () => {
            console.log(`New TotalFalse: ${this.state.totalFalse}`);
        });
    };
  } 

  render() {
    return (

  <div className="parallax">

    <div className="App">

        <div className="wrapper">

        <div className="headerDiv">
            <h1>Pixar Trivia!</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="timerDiv">
            <Timer 
            handleTimerClick={this.clickStart}
            timeOut={this.timerZero}
            />   
        </div>

        {this.state.showQuestions &&
        <div className="questionSection">
            <Questions 
                handleClickInParent={this.callbackHandlerFunction}
            />

            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        }

        {this.state.showResults && 
        <div className="resultsDiv">
            <Results 
                totalTrue={this.state.totalTrue}
                totalFalse={this.state.totalFalse}
            />
        </div>
        }

        </div>

    </div>

  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Timer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Timer extends Component {

  state = {
    timer: 10
  };

  startTimer = (event) => {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.setState({
      timer: this.state.timer - 1}), 1000); 
    // onClick, load Questions
    this.props.handleTimerClick(event);
   };

  stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    console.log("Time's up!");
    this.props.timeOut();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Timer">
        <div>{this.state.timer} seconds</div>
        <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start!</button>
        {this.state.timer === 0 && this.stopTimer()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Timer;
```

Comment: I think something is suspicious here:   `{this.state.timer === 0 && this.stopTimer()}` i.e it doesn't make sense. try calling  `this.stopTimer()` from inside `setTimeout` in `setState` callback

Comment: Hi Irene, I would suggest to check this:
`timerZero = () => {`
    `if (this.state.timer === 0) {`

Note that `timer` is not defined in the state of `class App`, therefor when you do `this.state.timer` it doesn't exists. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with your code, I'm just going to break up where the mistakes are.

### App.js

```
// ...
/* 
    you were trying to read this.state.timer
    which is not decalred in this component
*/
timerZero = () => this.setState(
        {showResults: true,
        showQuestions: false,
        showTimer: false}
    )

// ...

render() {

{/* ... */}
{this.state.showTimer && (
    <div className="timerDiv">
        <Timer 
        handleTimerClick={this.clickStart}
        timeOut={this.timerZero}
        />  
    </div>
{/* ... */
)}
```

### Timer.js

```
// ...

  /* 
    I added `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle
    with this, we stop the `Timer` component for rendering
    and call `stopTimer` (instead of doing it inside the render method)
  */
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state.timer);
    if (this.state.timer <= 0) {
      this.stopTimer();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
  /* 
    Also added the a componentWillUnmount method for good practice
    here if the component is unmounted the timer won't be running forever.
  */
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Timer">
        <div>{this.state.timer} seconds</div>
        <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start!</button>
        {/* delete the call to `this.stopTimer` */}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Also as an extra, I recommend you to ignore the `node_modules` folder in a `.gitignore` file to make your projects leaner. all your project dependencies are listed in `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` so when I download your repo I get to download the same dependencies you are using.

cheers!!!

Comment: Thank you for the gitignore reminder! The app works correctly now. I will have to take a closer look at lifecycles.

Comment: Glad, it worked!!! Yes, the lifecycles are really useful and cool to re-render less the components. And you just wait for the new `hooks` to be ready in January 2019 (they are available in `react@next`, they'll blow our mind!!!